# Naval officer crashes onto alien planet during Princess rescue attempt

Tags: story-identification, novel

I'm trying to recall a novel that featured a naval officer who crashes onto a planet with the rest of his squad to rescue an envoy who is actually the Princess of the Empire?

You find out the LT used to be a marine and in the sequel he designs a starship on his own and the shipyard builds it in secret, partially thwarting a conspiracy while the rest of the empires in the galaxy are driven back to his home planet.

Prior to the book he was bitten by a lizard on his home planet that causes him intense physical pain whenever he thinks of violence. He visits his home in the first book and is cured by the same lizard. You also discover that he previously rescued the prince as well and is awarded two medals by the king for rescuing his children. He also has fallen in love with the princess.

The book involves 'gravity plates' used for propulsion which were created by one man with the secret never revealed to anyone.

Comment: So was this a novel series?

Comment: https://www.amazon.com/Princess-Ryans-Star-Marines-Save/dp/1466218487

Comment: Correct, as of mid 2015 it was 2 books but I don't know if any have been added since then. It is not Princess Ryan's Star Marines.